# Ag-Grid | setRowCount with SSRM

Tags: ag-grid

I am using the Server Side Row Model (SSRM) with my AgGrids. Up until now, I had my custom Datasource fetch both the total number of rows and the next page of results each time getRows was invoked. This works, but it was not very efficient. Computing the total number of rows can be a costly operation, and it was causing very noticeable delays once scaled to production levels of data with hundreds of millions of rows on some tables.

As such, I am now attempting to only compute the number of rows both on the initial load and whenever the filters change. To support this, I have removed the ability for my datasource to fetch the count and am performing this asynchronously via the onGridReady and onFilterChanged events.

The request to retrieve the total count succeeds - but when I pass the count to the grid api, it doesn't appear to update the grid properly at all. My code looks like this:

```
    const apiRef = useRef<GridApi>();
    
    const updateRowCount = useCallback(async () => {
      if(apiRef.current) {
        myApi.getRowCount({
          filterModel: apiRef.current.getFilterModel()
        }).then(count => {
          apiRef.current?.setRowCount(count, true);
        }).catch(reason => {
          console.error(reason);
        });
      }
    }, [myApi]);

    const onFilterChanged = useCallback((e: FilterChangedEvent) => {
      updateRowCount();
    }, [updateRowCount]);
    
    const onGridReady = useCallback((e: GridReadyEvent) => {
      apiRef.current = e.api;
      updateRowCount();
    }, [updateRowCount]);
```

Note that I have confirmed that the updateRowCount function is being called at the apprioriate times, it is sending the request and recieving the response successfully, and no errors are being thrown. So the problem should lie solely with how to make the setRowCount function work properly. Perhaps that function is not appropriate for SSRM and there is an alternate way to do this?

My expectation is two-fold. First, the vertical scrollbar on the Grid is sized appropriately so that I can scroll down the last records as per the count; even if the rows haven't been loaded yet. Second, a ModelChanged event is fired and the DisplayedRowCount is updated accordingly.

I am currently on version ^28 of AgGrid (enterprise)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bug in ag-grid.

Why `setRowCount` method doesn't work as you expect. I've debugged it and looks like internally it invokes a setter on the `cache` object. That setter doesn't work if the initial property is empty.
So, as a workaround, you can set rowCount initially in your `datasource.getRows` method. But you need to do it only once. After that, when you call `setRowCount(count, true)` it will work as expected.

Example of how you may modify datasource, to initiate `rowCount`:

```js
const datasource = {
  initiated: false,
  getRows: function ({success}) {
    ...
    if(this.initiated) {
      success({ rowData: result });
    } else {
      success({ rowData: result, rowCount: result.length });
    }
    this.initiated = true;
  }
}
```

I've tried this workaround on v30, and it works.

NOTE: I assume, after applying filter/sorting the inner cache is destroyed, so probably `rowCount` should be reinitiated again.

Comment: Oh that’s interesting. Thank you for taking the time to debug this :)